# Finding the minimum and maximum value of $x$ using the domain of $\arcsin$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, inverse-function

In my textbook, there's this problem:

> (i) $\arcsin {2x \sqrt {1 - x^2}} = 2\arcsin {x}, \frac {-1}{\sqrt {2}} \leq x \leq \frac {1}{\sqrt {2}}$
>
> (ii) $\arcsin {2x \sqrt {1 - x^2}} = 2\arccos {x}, \frac {1}{\sqrt {2}} \leq x \leq 1$

I know how to solve this question, but my question is how did they know what the minimum and maximum values of $x$ are? And how is that relevant to the particular question?

I tried defining the range of $x$ by taking the inequality:

$$ -1 \leq 2x \sqrt {1 - x^2} \leq 1 $$
as that is the domain of the $\arcsin$ function. Unfortunately, I couldn't procceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that the range of the arcsine function is $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.  Thus, in the first equation, we require that
$$-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{1 - x^2}\right) = 2\arcsin x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
-\frac{\pi}{4} & \leq \arcsin x \leq \frac{\pi}{4}\\
\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) & \leq x \leq \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \leq x \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{align*}

We know that the range of the arcsine function $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ and that range of the arccosine function is $[0, \pi]$.  Therefore, if $x$ satisfies the equation
$$\arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{1 - x^2}\right) = 2\arccos x,$$
then
$$0 \leq \arcsin\left(2x\sqrt{1 - x^2}\right) = 2\arccos x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$
since the solution must lie in the intersection of their domains.  Keep in mind that the arccosine function is decreasing.  Can you proceed from here?